# Do SQL Server and WAMP Server clash? Do I need to use different ports?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008, apache

Alright, I am totally new to programming so be easy on me.  I followed the instructions from my Lynda.com account on how to install WampServer for Windows 7 but run I am unable to get my orange icon to change to green.  I have tried to connect to "put it online" but received the following error:

"Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The service has not been started"

So I restarted all services with the same error.  I also tried stopping services then restarting.  No luck and I still get the same error.

Some following things to keep in mind:

- I already have SQL Server installed before I tried to install WAMP Server so wonder if they're linked to the same port.  If so, not sure how to find and edit this port.

-I do not have SKYPE so they are not using the same port.

My theory is it's having something to do with having SQL Server and MySQL using the same port.  How do I change a port if so.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: The default port for MS SQL Server is 1433 and MySQL is 3306. Unless you changed them, they are not competing. I am also not sure how to find what ports are being used, etc in Windows. If it were Unix/Linux I would have your answer after a couple commands.

Comment: Why do you need two DBMS? Just install apache and php and use SQL Server if you don't need MySQL. But that most likely wouldn't be causign this problem. Check the logs for the servers (apache and mysql) and see which one is throwing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem and found that it is not the SQL server which is conflicting, but the SQL server Reporting service. I went to **services.msc** and stopped SQL **server Reporting service**. I also chagned it to **manual** so that it does not start **automatically** on a reboot. Now I restarted WAMP server and it turned green.

Tnx-
SJ Creation

Answer (score 2):

You can Test Port 80 by clicking on the Wamp Server, Apache, Service, then Test Port 80. If it is being used, it will tell you otherwise it will tell you that it is not being used at that instance.

Stopping SQL Reporting Service, Start, then type Administrative Tools, click on the name , select computer Management, then Services and applications> SQL Server Configuration> Services & Look for SQL Reporting Servicves, Set it to Manual start, and stop.

Restart Your WAMP Server, Test Ur Port, This time U will not find it BUSY. Restart all Services.

for more to change port or other problem please check [here](http://sreypoevitc.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/resolving-yellow-wamp-server-status/)

hope it can help you

Comment: I didn't think I needed 2 DBMS either but thought maybe there was something I didn't know.  Anyway, I was able to fix by installing apache and PHP individually then configuring with SQL Server.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps

1. Change the port number from 80 to something like 8888 (in the thousands) - to change the port number you must click on the wamp or mamp and then click on apache then click on httpd.conf and then searchfor listen. Change the port number to 4444 or 8888 or something in the thousands.
2. if wamp is now working but you still get

Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

you must right the absolute path as follow

localhost:8888/folderName/filename.php

this should fix your problem

Also: you can go to dreamweaver and click on server. Then place localhost:8888 instead of simply using localhost

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and found that it is not the SQL server which is conflicting, but the SQL server Reporting service. It seems it is using same port 3306 which is being used by MYSql. I went to services.msc and stopped SQL server Reporting service. I also chagned it to manual so that it does not start automatically on a reboot. Now I restarted WAMP server and it turned green.

Presently I am not using SQL server Reporting services, hence I can keep the service stopped. I have no idea how I can change the port for this service so that they don't conflict. If any one really wants to use SQL server Reporting services, he or she may dig deeper into this service to somehow change the port.

Thanks,

Pankaj